# How to override npm peerinvalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-managers

I'm attempting to install a node module that has specified a `peerDependencies` to an older version of a package. I know that module will work with the newer version. How can I tell npm to ignore the `peerinvalid` error? Currently the `peerinvalid` error is stoping the installation process.

This is the error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer xxx@x.x.x wants xxx@x.x.x
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what does it want? Please post the rest of the error message.

Comment: @shmuli, thanks for you comment. I'm, actually not interested in supplying the dependency. I would like to know how to force npm to continue the installation process, in spite of a `peerinvalid` error. If you're really curious it's react v`0.12.x`, v`0.13.0` was just released, but many modules have a peerDependency of `0.12.x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NPM v3 peer dependancies show a warning instead of an error.

> We will also be changing the behavior of peerDependencies in npm@3. We won’t be automatically downloading the peer dependency anymore. Instead, we’ll warn you if the peer dependency isn’t already installed. This requires you to resolve peerDependency conflicts yourself, manually, but in the long run this should make it less likely that you’ll end up in a tricky spot with your packages’ dependencies.

http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5

Answer (score 1):

A really hacky/temporary workaround is to modify the package.json of the installed packages with the peerDependency specified, deleting the lines that specify react as a peerDependency.

This hack will go away if you (or a colleague) need to `npm install` your package's requirements from scratch. Like I said, a crappy temporary workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that was an option, I was just hoping for a better solution. The good news is it looks like npm v3 will only issue a warning, not an error: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565#issuecomment-74971689